# Which countries (if any) allow beyond-line-of-sight drone use?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, regulations

I was recently thinking about starting up a non-profit that would use large drones (full scale aircraft, not those dinky quadcopters) to deliver humanitarian aid to difficult locations.

It was shot down pretty quickly when I remembered that civilians aren't allowed to fly unmanned systems beyond [the visual] line of sight (BLOS).

So, this led me to my question, are there any countries that allow BLOS use of civilian unmanned aircraft?

Comment: Don't stop pursueing a good idea because current day regulations are blocking. They will change. BLOS will be used for this kind of purposes. There is work going on to integrate this class of [UAV's in the ATC system](https://www.dfs.de/dfs_homepage/en/Press/Press%20releases/2016/15.11.2016.-%20High-level%20cooperation/). This is not for dinky quadcopters but for unmanned aircraft that are certified to meet many requirements  before the are allowed for BLOS. There is a clear move into that direction and the regulations will change once the technical and operational problem are addressed.

Comment: [Rwanda](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/05/27/how-rwanda-is-using-drones-to-save-millions-of-lives.html) is one it seems. You may want to get in touch with the government of the intended area of operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. You have all been very helpful with your answers. I am sure that in the countries in which it's not yet regulated and therefore still not legal, it will soon become regulated. It's just a game of waiting for the legislatures to do their jobs.

Answer (score 7):

The current situation (November 2018) regarding beyond visual line of sight operations (BVLOS) is heterogeneous:

- Overall, not allowed in Europe, but there are notable exceptions where BVLOS is explicitly regulated, see below.
- Regulated in Canada
- Regulated in a few countries in Asia, Africa and Latin America.
- Not allowed in the US

**US**

UAVs fall under [Part 107](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=dc908fb739912b0e6dcb7d7d88cfe6a7&mc=true&node=pt14.2.107&rgn=div5) operations which prevents BVLOS (107.31). [Waivers](https://www.faa.gov/uas/request_waiver/) can be requested, but only [27 have been granted](https://www.faa.gov/uas/request_waiver/waivers_granted/) to date (enter "107.31" in the search box).

**European Union or EASA member states**

EASA is the European safety agency. For [EASA member states](https://www.easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/international-cooperation/easa-by-country) (EU and a few other countries), there are two opposite situations today:

With no surprise *North European countries* (Iceland, Norway, Sweden), with many isolated locations have allowed BVLOS operations early, including for delivery of goods to consumers, e.g. [Aha, an online marketplace, delivers goods using drones in Iceland](https://www.aha.is/en/drone-delivery). Not only this is BVLOS, but it's even automated.

*Many countries* don't allow it but they are waiting for a EU regulation that would allow them. Actually current opinion of the EASA is it must be allowed (but more for industrial uses than for good delivery to public):

> EASA will develop standard scenarios that will make it simpler to
>   obtain authorisations for well‑defined operations (such as, for
>   example, linear inspections conducted in BVLOS, or crop spraying).

([Source](https://www.easa.europa.eu/newsroom-and-events/press-releases/easa-publishes-first-opinion-safe-drone-operations-europe))

In their declaration EASA mentions linear inspections, which has been actually something done in France since a long time for railways catenaries and electric grid lines.

*France* has kept with its pioneering role in aviation. BVLOS is regulated since 2012. A company located in Toulouse, another well known place for aviation, paved this road. As I'm not going to do their advertising, I let you read about them online, e.g. last year they were able to have a [50-km civilian flight with a 3G data link](https://delair.aero/drone-completes-bvlos-flight-via-3g/).

*Switzerland*

If you are asking for your home country, Switzerland, which is also an EASA member state:

> [image]

LOS is required, but waivers are possible, though there are no public criteria provided, so you need to try, when you have defined all the details of your project.

As [DeltaLima](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/19/deltalima) mentioned (maybe with a good insider knowledge) laws are rapidly evolving in the domain, as does UAV technology.

**Around the World**

Taken from [International Commercial Drone Regulation and Drone Delivery Services](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_reports/RR1700/RR1718z3/RAND_RR1718z3.pdf) by Rand Corporation:

> For countries that have drone regulations, these regulations typically
>   incorporate a pilot’s license, registration of the drone, restricted
>   zones, and insurance; regulation requirements vary based on such
>   parameters as drone mass, population density, altitude, and use cases.

and the list of countries in 2017:

> [image]

As visible there are legal possibility for BVLOS in many countries and across all continents.

**Permission limits**

Same document, excerpt for three countries:

> [image]

For France already mentioned, we see the BVLOS is authorized up to 1 km for 2 kg+ mass, and unlimited below (but constraints like pilot license and registration still apply). Looking at the criteria for a permissive country:

> [image]

Well, except height and insurance in certain cases, there is no other ones!

**Future market**

While B2B application have a large market, the B2C market is huge in an era of online sales and home delivery. Amazon is waiting for (experimentation in Japan), as quick food businesses do, for their delivery.

Comment: Iceland is not a member of the EU. It does appear to be a member of the European Economic Area, which is the same status as that of Norway. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland%E2%80%93European_Union_relations This is potentially a bit confusing since you list it under a "European Union" heading.

Comment: @aCVn, You're right, they probably wouldn't appreciate being said EU members. That said, the confusion is because they are full [EASA member states](https://www.easa.europa.eu/country-category/easa-member-states).

Comment: That's clearer.